# Why regex doesn't work in collect

Tags: ruby, regex

So trying to run this on the model `HomeLoan` and gives me a bug:

```
HomeLoan.columns.collect {|x| p /month/.match(x.name.to_s)}
SyntaxError: (irb):30: syntax error, unexpected '.'
HomeLoan.columns.collect {|x| p /month/.match(x.name.to_s)}
                                        ^
```

???

However when I run:

`/month/.match("month")` succeeds....

Slightly confused in here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a fully functional example? That structure works fine for me in Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, and 2.0.0. Perhaps the error is actually elsewhere and only manifesting itself at that `.`.

Comment: I'd suspect a non-terminated regex a line or two higher up

Comment: Dunno, what was that. I just exited and entered console, and it worked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
HomeLoan.columns.collect {|x| /month/.match(x.name.to_s)}
```

Comment: what wrong with OP's code then.. Is `p` the culprit?

Comment: I don't think there was anything syntactically wrong. But, because he was using `#collect`, using `p` wouldn't get him any result.

Comment: so as he mentioned about the error `SyntaxError: (irb):30: syntax error, unexpected '.'`.. I am looking for why does it come?

Comment: I think he forgot to "Control C". Maybe a trailing `end` he forgotten to clear for example. Happens to me all the time.